# DoubleRenderError when use render in both called and caller method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie with Ruby on Rails.

This code returns `DoubleRenderError`:

```
class PostapisController < ApplicationController
    def method1
       method2()
       render json: {:success: false}
    end 

    def method2
       render json: {:status => 'ok'} and return
    end 
end
```

Why does it return `DoubleRenderError`? How can I fix it if I still want both `method1()` and `method2()` to call `render`?

Answer (score 1):

"render" and "redirect_to" are both ways to generate the response to the request your server received.  The server can only give one response to each request, so you can't render twice.

In your case, you should be able to appreciate that it doesn't make sense to send a  `{:success: false}`  response AND send a `{:status => 'ok'}` response: it's got to be one or the other, right?  That's not a rails thing, it's just a web thing.  One response per request.

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, so can't advise any further, other than by telling you to read some more basic stuff about Rails before starting to use it.

Comment: Thanks. This code is only a simple example. Method2 can render or not (by using if statement in that ). If method2 rendered then I want exit method1 (not render). That is my idea. Can't i fix it ?

Comment: In that case you need to return after method2 is called inside of method1. The "and return" is only returning you from method2, not telling method1 to stop evaluating.